# TFLiteConverter on tensorflow 1.14 in raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a code for convert tflite. it is the code:

```
 from tensorflow import lite
from tensorflow.keras              

import models
# Parameters
keras_model_filename =         

'wake_word_stop_model.h5'
tflite_filename =     'wake_word_stop_lite.tflite'

# Convert model to TF Lite   

 model
 model =   models.load_model(keras_model_     filename)
converter       
   =lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model =           
converter.convert()
 open(tflite_filename,     
'wb').write(tflite_model
```

'''
but this code error. with message AttributeError: type object 'TFLiteConverter' has no attribute 'from_keras_model'

Answer (score 0):

`from_keras_model` is an API of Tensorflow 2.x

You could use `from_keras_model_file` API

But I'd suggest to consider an upgrade to 2.x version

Comment: i upgrage to 2.x but i got a message No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.2.0

Comment: I suggest you to ask another question. That will help you to make it visible and also will help other people with the same problems to find it